# Retrieving latitude/longitude from TIFF with GeoTools

Tags: geotools, image, latitude-longitude, geotiff-tiff

I am new to GeoTools and I have to work on project which includes a set of tiff image maps. In that I need to get latitude/longitude for a given point.

Ex: When mouse click occurs I want to get the lat/long for the clicked point.

I tried following code snippet

```
frame.getMapPane().addMouseListener(
            new MapMouseAdapter(){
                public void onMouseClicked(MapMouseEvent ev) {
                
                    //DirectPosition2D pos = ev.getMapPosition();
                    //System.out.println(pos.x + " " + pos.y);
                    DirectPosition2D pos = ev.getWorldPos();
                    System.out.println(pos.x + " " + pos.y);
                    
                }
            }
            
    );
```

Are these simply the X/Y coordinates for a given point?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those are the position of the point in "World" coordinates, that is what ever your map is using as it's projection. This may or may not be lat/lon.